# Symfony 2 Form: how to bind data

Tags: symfony

How to bind data which is gained by using call:

```
$attributes = $em->getRepository('\OBB\Entity\Attribute')->findAllWithAllRelations($id);
```

to a Symfony 2 Form

Because according to a manual you need to have a method defined in Entity which is bound to a form.

Comment: Well you should have a getter, like getAttributes.
Apart from that, if that code is inside your entity: do not use the entity manager inside an entiy ...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a form type for editing an individual attribute. This could look something like:

```
namespace OBB\Form;

class AttributeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'OBB\Entity\Attribute',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'obb_attribute';
    }
}
```

Then you can use a collection form to edit a collection of them simultaneously.

```
$form = $this->createForm('collection', $attributes, array(
    'type' => new AttributeType(),
));
```